# Counting <ul> height with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, height

Here's my situation. I have a sliding jquery menu like this: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/03/sliding-background-image-menu.

The code of menu is:

```
<div id="sbi_container" class="sbi_container">
        <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/1.jpg">
            <a href="#" class="sbi_label">About</a>
            <div class="sbi_content">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Subitem</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/2.jpg">
            ...
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sbi_content{
    position:absolute;
    border-top:2px solid #000;
    bottom:90px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    background:transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left;
    display:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.sbi_content ul{
    padding:10px;
}
.sbi_content ul a{
    display:block;
    color:#f0f0f0;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:4px 6px 4px 14px;
    background:transparent url(../images/triangle.png) no-repeat 3px 50%;
    opacity:0.9;
}
.sbi_content ul a:hover{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #000;
}
```

And here's a JavaScript piece I have a problem with:

```
    $content.each(function(i) {
            var $el = $(this);
// save each content's height (where the menu items are)
// and hide them by setting the height to 0px
            var num = $el.find('ul li').size();

            $el.data( 'height', num * 35 + 10 ).css( 'height', '0px' ).show();
                    });
```

I need to count a height of these `<ul>`.
That I'm doing now is counting how many there are `<li>` items, then multiply it by number of one's height (35) and adding a 10px for margin..

Everything would be ok, but when there is a realy long `<li>` item, it jumps to second row and problem is that this code doesn't count that second row height.

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried: `$('#your-ul').outerHeight()`

Comment: Yes I've tried this, and then strage things going on. You can see it here: http://www.vladsworkshop.lt/newsite/

When there is more than one word in <li> item, id adds a seperate space below submenu.. I really dont know why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `scrollHeight` property:

```
$("ul")[0].scrollHeight
```

For your specific case -

```
$content.find('ul')[0].scrollHeight
```

Comment: When write:
`var num = $el.find('ul')[0].scrollHeight;`

It counts for me that num=0. Why?

Comment: It's kind a strange, because everything what I can find is:
`var $el = $(this);` (you can see it in my main post in a first line of Java script). Or this is not it?

Comment: `var  $content = $el.find('div.sbi_content')`

Comment: you don't need $content.each()... you can directly do $content.find('ul')[0].scrollHeight... infact just do $('div.sbi_content ul')[0].scrollHeight to get the height of ul

Comment: Hmm.. I starting to understant. But how should I wrinte all this in case then I at the end need to get  `$el.data( 'height', "number" ).css( 'height', '0px' ).show();
                    });` ?

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english.. :) I got it! :)
I Think it works! :) Thank you soooo much!

I used your first idea with `$content.find('ul')[0].scrollHeight`, because I got many different submenus in `div.sbicontent`.. So I needed it to work individualy on every different submenu..

Maybe you could post this in as new answer, and I will check it as a rigth? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can count the height of all the `li`s in the content using this:

```
var totalLiHeight = 0;
$el.find('ul li').each(function() {
    var currentLiHeight = $(this).height();
    totalLiHeight += currentLiHeight;
});
```

Then you can add the margin to that.